# Minus Enum causes error in vector

Tags: c++, vector, enums

I have an enum like this in a static class:

```
enum 
{
BLOCK1,
BLOCK2,
BLOCK3,
BLOCK4,
BLOCK5,
ERROR = -1
};
```

In the real code there are over 200 in the enum.  The order is important.

Later on, I need to get a number based on the HW input.

```
vector<vector<int8_t>> HWConfig
{
    {BLOCK1, BLOCK5, ERROR},
    {BLOCK3, BLOCK1, ERROR},
    {BLOCK1, BLOCK2, ERROR},
}
```

The vectors are usually small, 18x18 is the max.  Not all the values in the enum are ever in the vector of vector.  I have many vectors of vectors, which give different numbers.  I search the number, so, if I want row 1, `BLOCK5`, I return number 1.

The trouble is that with `ERROR`, I get the compiler message

```
error: ‘TH::<anonymous enum>’ is/uses anonymous type
error:   trying to instantiate ‘template<class _E> class std::initializer_list’
```

If I replace `ERROR` with -1, then it works.

An example would be this:  The user calls the function like this:

```
TH::getDEMOD(1, TH::ERROR);

TH::getDEMOD(uint8_t index, int8_t block)
{
vector<vector<int8_t>> HWConfig
{
    {BLOCK1, BLOCK5, ERROR},
    {BLOCK3, BLOCK1, ERROR},
    {BLOCK1, BLOCK2, ERROR},
};
return TH::find(HWConfig, index, block);
}
```

This should return 2

Comment: Can you construct a minimal test-case?

Comment: [Seems to compile and run OK for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92ab7c43618d9501) - what compiler and command-line switches are you using ?

Comment: 1. Post the **complete** error message. The compiler is saying with which types it's trying to instantiate, and we need to see that. You basically posted an equivalent of "I am unable to build a house from". From what? 2. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As an aside, you say you have more than 200 enums, but you are using `int8_t`. It doesn't sound like that has sufficient range for your enum values, if we assume all but `ERROR` are positive.

Comment: Any chance of the test-case?

Comment: Is ERROR defined to be something in the global namespace? If you name it MY_ERROR, does it still cause the issue?

Comment: Testcase on the way.  I changed it to MY_ERROR and still I have the error.  Changed to int16_t too.

Comment: Given that the error is complaining about it being an anonymous enum, and it seems they're treated differently to named types with regard to template parameters, have you tried naming the enum? ie `enum BlockType { BLOCK1, BLOCK2, ERROR = -1 };`

Comment: @etheranger, Thanks it was that simple to fix.